# Using SharedPreferences to store state of checkbox within a listview

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How would I use shared preferences to store the state of my checkbox for the next time the app is opened? I'm using a custom adapter so am guessing it has to be placed inside that but I'm not quite sure.

My Adapter:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_adapter, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;


        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter,
                    parent, false);
        }
           // in your code you search for the CheckBox with the id checkBox1 2 times so I assumed that you are referring to the same view.
        CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cBox.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        cBox.setText(values[position]);       
        cBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    itemChecked.set(position, true);
                    // do some operations here
                } else {
                    itemChecked.set(position, false);
                    // do some operations here
                }
            }
        });
        cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

My main Activity:

```
public class TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private String[] myString;
private String list;
private String[] myString2;
private String list2;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
private static final Random rgenerator2 = new Random();
MediaPlayer mp;
final Context mContext = this;
final Context context = this;
private Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    addListenerOnButton();




    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

    list = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

    myString2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray2);

    list2 = myString2[rgenerator.nextInt(myString2.length)];
}



    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context2 = this;

        ImageButton ibg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttongallery);

        ibg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context2, App2Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);   

            }

        });


    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View erica) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity.this);
            b.setMessage(myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);
            b.setTitle(R.string.title1);
            b.setIcon(R.drawable.menuiconerica);
            b.setPositiveButton("Back",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            Dialog d = b.create();
            d.show();
        }
    });

    ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
    ib2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View kevin) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity.this);
            b.setMessage(myString2[rgenerator2.nextInt(myString2.length)]);
            b.setTitle(R.string.title2);
            b.setIcon(R.drawable.menuiconkevin);
            b.setPositiveButton("Back",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            Dialog d = b.create();
            d.show();

        }
    });


    ImageButton Ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton3);
    Ib3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View lemonclick) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.lemonspeech);
            mp.start();


        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list);
        dialog.setTitle("The List");


        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        //TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        //text.setText("Did you not read the button? :P i'm not finshed on this yet XD");


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        String[] values = new String[] { "value1", "value2", };


        MobileArrayAdapter mAdapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), values);
        ListView mListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.myList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }

    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `OnCLickListener` for your `Button` add this:

```
//...
// custom dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list);
dialog.setTitle("The List");

prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
String currentlyStored = prefs.getString("checked_list", null);
int[] savedStatus = null;
if (currentlyStored != null) {
    String[] tmp = currentlyStored.split(",");
    savedStatus = new int[tmp.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        savedStatus[i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);
    }
}
adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this, soundnames, savedStatus);
ListView mListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.myList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//...
```

where:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
private MobileArrayAdapter adapter;
```

are fields in your class with the `ListView`(the `adapter` field will hold your adapter object that you set on the list).

Modify the constructor of your custom adapter like this:

```
public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values,
                int[] oldStatus) {
            super(context, R.layout.adapters_simpleplay_row, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;

            // make every CheckBox unchecked and then loop through oldStatus(if
            // not null)
            for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
                itemChecked.add(i, false);
            }
            if (oldStatus != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < oldStatus.length; j++) {
                    itemChecked.set(oldStatus[j], true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Also add  the following method in your custom adapter `MobileArrayAdapter`:

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> getCheckedStatus() {
            return itemChecked;
}
```

Last in the listener for your `dialogButton` add this:

```
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            String toStore = "";
            ArrayList<Boolean> status = adapter.getCheckedStatus();
            for (int i = 0; i < status.size(); i++) {
                if (status.get(i)) {
                    toStore += i + ",";
                }
            }
            prefsEditor.putString("checked_list", toStore.equals("") ? null
                    : toStore.substring(0, toStore.length() - 1));
            prefsEditor.commit();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @CarbonAssassin soundnames is your String array from the custom adapter constructor `String[] values`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I get this error The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

Comment: @CarbonAssassin Modify that line like this: `getDefaultSharedPreferences(TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity.this)`

Comment: My application now crashes with a nullpointerexecption at kevin.erica.box.TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity$5$1.onClick(TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity.java:190)

Comment: @CarbonAssassin which line is 190 in the `TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity` class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10406/discussion-between-carbonassassin-and-luksprog)

Answer (score 1):

To save selections make a method saveSelections and call it in `onPause()` and `onDestroy()`, or create a Button to do the same for you...
Edit:

Since you are using a `ListView` which is MultipleChoice I suppose you can do this in onCreate...

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Create these three methods outside onCreate()

```
private void LoadSelections() {
        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sp.contains(LOAD_LIST)) {
            String savedItems = sp.getString(LOAD_LIST, "");
            this.selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));
            int count = this.listView.getAdapter().getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String currentItem = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                if (this.selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                    this.listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveSelections() {
        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sp.edit();
        String savedItems = getSavedItems();
        prefEditor.putString(LOAD_LIST, savedItems);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private String getSavedItems() {
        String savedItems = "";
        int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (listView.isItemChecked(i)) {
                if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                    savedItems += "," + listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                } else {
                    savedItems += listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return savedItems;
    }
```

Then in onPause(), do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SaveSelections();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Then finally in onCreate call this..

```
LoadSelections();
```

Comment: Where would i place the first piece of code? and would i not need to place anything in the if statements of my adapter?

Comment: I gave you an abstract idea as to what you can do, you will have to do every thing I said in an Activity where you set the Adapter, follow this approach, it will solve your problem.

Comment: And im placing this in my main activity im guessing?

Comment: I'm just trying to implement it, Would you be able to give me a hand if i put up my main activty code?

Comment: its easy, just try to fit pieces together, I can confirm you have everything you need to do what you want...

Comment: Would you quickly have a look at my main activity? shared preferences really confuse me :/

Comment: Here you go, this is a tutorial you need, http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10403/discussion-between-carbonassassin-and-mirroredabstraction)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string of 0 & 1 and store it using shared preference. The number of checkboxes (or the number of view) you are using will be the length of string. You save it accordingly.

Eg:

```
String s[]="0000000000";
for (i=0;i<s.length();i++)
if (checkboxAtLocation(i)==true)    //checkboxAtLocation() will return a boolean variable on basis of its checked or not
    s[i]=1;
```

Now store this string.
On starting activity again, use this string to set the checkbox.

This is bit complex to implement but most efficient way as per my knowledge.
I hope it solves your doubt.

Comment: i preferably need help on all steps as ive never used shared preferences before. if you need me to put more code up i can but i really need exact implantation :)

Comment: Need to write lot of code. Sometime needed. Till that you can try this- make a static string s[]="00000000". Update it as the view are added in getView() method. And save the string in shared preference. While starting the app, use this to mark the check box. Comment if you get it or have doubts.